# ng-Include: evaluator function never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML:

```
    <section ng-controller="NavigationController as navCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="navCtrl.setNav(1)" ng-class="{ 'myApp_nav_items_selected': navCtrl.isNavPage(1) , 'myApp_nav_items': !navCtrl.isNavPage(1) }"><a ng-class="{ 'myApp_nav_selected_a': navCtrl.isNavPage(1) , 'myApp_nav_a': !navCtrl.isNavPage(1) }" href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li ng-click="navCtrl.setNav(2)" ng-class="{ 'myApp_nav_items_selected': navCtrl.isNavPage(2) , 'myApp_nav_items': !navCtrl.isNavPage(2) }"><a ng-class="{ 'myApp_nav_selected_a': navCtrl.isNavPage(2) , 'myApp_nav_a': !navCtrl.isNavPage(2) }" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li ng-click="navCtrl.setNav(3)" ng-class="{ 'myApp_nav_items_selected': navCtrl.isNavPage(3) , 'myApp_nav_items': !navCtrl.isNavPage(3) }"><a ng-class="{ 'myApp_nav_selected_a': navCtrl.isNavPage(3) , 'myApp_nav_a': !navCtrl.isNavPage(3) }" href="#">Option 3</a></li>    
    </ul>

    <div class="myAppta_page">
    <div ng-include="navCtrl.getPage()"></div>      
    </div>
    </section>
```

JS

```
tripdataApp.controller('NavigationController', function ($scope) {
   this.$scope = $scope; 
   this.$scope.navPage =1;

    this.setNav = function(theNavPage) {   <--- WORKS OK
       console.log("set nav " + theNavPage);
        this.$scope.navPage = theNavPage;
        console.log("nav IS set to " +  this.$scope.navPage);
    }; 

    this.isNavPage = function(checkNavPage) {   <---- WORKS OK
        return this.$scope.navPage === checkNavPage;
    };

    this.getPage = function() {      <---- NEVER CALLED

         console.log("-=-=-=-=- nav IS set to " +  this.$scope.navPage);


        switch (this.$scope.navPage)
        {
            case 1: 
                console.log("dashboard");
                return "#/pages/dashboard.php";
                break;
            default:
                console.log("ddefault");
                return "#/pages/unimplemented.php";
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's with the closing `<div />` after the list?

Comment: I fixed and edited. still this function isn't called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per I can see in the docs, there is no reference saying that you can evaluate a controller method within an ng-include directive. Other than that, it does say that you can use a constant but you have to add single quotes wrapping up the content of the ng-include.

For more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

I think a different approach is the solution for this issue.

Comment: What approach might that be? physical removal of div content and injection of html content via ng-click?

Comment: <div ng-include="navCtrl.getPage()"></div> should load the first page (without calling the function, just the string pointing where it should grab the template from) and then dinamically fetch the templates and inject them in the html. Another good thing would be considering using ngRoute and ngView as theyr apis are pretty awesome.